# Handle Activity Resize when going FullScreen

Tags: android

In my Android app, when I switch to full screen mode using the following piece of code:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

the screen goes to full screen by hiding the notification bar at the top. The notification bar animates out of the visible space, but the activity expands with a jerk. During the time when the notification bar is hiding, the space is taken up by a white area. And when the notification hiding completes, the activity resizes.

How can I allow the activity to expand with animation? For that the question to answer will be how to handle the activity size changed in this scenario?

I already tried handling onConfigurationChanged() - doesn't hit (after supplying screenSize in android:configChanges for my activity in the manifest)

The same thing happens when hiding the action bar. The action bar hides with animation leaving a white space behind it. And when it is done the activity fits in with a jerk! Arggh!

Comment: did u try onSizeChanged? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int)

Comment: onSizeChanged is on a View not on the Activity. The activity that I have has multiple views so not possible to handle onSizeChanged of all the views.

Comment: But you can try onSizeChanged() method for your root-layout in activity.